# Why are my layouts not showing up?

Tags: android, layout

I have a header layout that programmatically needs to be divided into 3 equally sized layouts. I tried weights, but nothing showed up, so I hardcoded the height in there and the root layout (extra header) becomes bigger. So they are working but the background color I have assigned them to doesn't show up, the button that is supposed to show inside the right layout doesn't show up and when I use weights instead of hardcoded numbers, the layouts are also not visible. Am I missing something?

```
    private void SetHeader(LinearLayout extraHeader)
    {
        ImageView btnSettings = new ImageView(this);

        btnSettings.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.general_btn_dots_horizontal);
        btnSettings.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

        LinearLayout lnLeft = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout lnCenter = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout lnRight = new LinearLayout(this);

        extraHeader.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpWeights = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 500);
        //lpWeights.Weight = 33;

        lnLeft.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
        lnCenter.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
        lnRight.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);

        lnLeft.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#222222"));
        lnCenter.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#333333"));
        lnRight.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#444444"));

        lnLeft.LayoutParameters = lpWeights;
        lnCenter.LayoutParameters = lpWeights;
        lnRight.LayoutParameters = lpWeights;

        lnRight.AddView(btnSettings);

        extraHeader.AddView(lnLeft);
        extraHeader.AddView(lnCenter);
        extraHeader.AddView(lnRight);
    }
```

Also: Making the extra header orientation vertical shows my layouts right... only on top of one another and not side by side...

Comment: lnleft, lncenter and lnright should all be the same size filling the extraheader? have you tried setting the size of extraheader, and setttings the lpWeights  Layout Params to matchParent, and the weight to 1.

Comment: eventually they souuld. but the weights didnt work so i set the size (200,500). but when they are alligned horizontally, they dont show. they do however show, when alligned vertically..?!

Answer (score 0):

Remember folks: If the layout already has children (i.e.: from the xml) REMOVEALLVIEWS()